# Explorer 11 Header location to div ID not working

Tags: internet-explorer, header, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I've a problem trying to redirect to a specific div id in explorer. The code is working in chrome and Firefox but not in explorer 11

The code is just similar to that:

```
header("Location: http://myurl.com/page1#id1");
```

Is this a known problem in explorer?

Comment: I currently use similar code to this in a locally hosted system. I seem to be having no problems loading such a url in IE, as i use this for my documentation page, and have links directing to entries by the DIV as you have.

Comment: Can you post the HTML code that you are using? Do you have the correct Doctype for HTML5 or XHTML, because it likely wouldn't work for a document being identified by IE as HTML4.

Comment: When I say 'post the HTML' I mean the HTML used in the target document. Most likely problem is a syntax error of some sort.